# Ignore parskip if using dialogue package

Tags: koma-script, parskip, dialogue, scrartcl

I am using the `dialogue` package in my document and I'm using `scrartcl` with option `parskip`.

How can I switch off `parskip` inside the dialogues? I don’t want to have that space between the lines.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dialogue}

\begin{document}

Some text: ergk kfjnw kjeb oqie kebwueb  ueibr iwube b iueb uf bwieu beu bwob bk jbwbekjbf bwjeb bfuweij bkjejbrkjwb j.

Some more text ...

Beginn of the Dialogue
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{Tim} Hi, how are you?
\speak{Karl} I think thats obvious!
\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

How can I delete the space between TIM and KARL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `\PreDialogue` to switch of option `parskip` inside the environment:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dialogue}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\apptocmd{\PreDialogue}{\KOMAoption{parskip}{false}}{}{\undefined}

\begin{document}

Some text: ergk kfjnw kjeb oqie kebwueb  ueibr iwube b iueb uf bwieu beu bwob bk jbwbekjbf bwjeb bfuweij bkjejbrkjwb j.

Some more text ...

Beginn of the Dialogue
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{Tim} Hi, how are you?
\speak{Karl} I think thats obvious!
\end{dialogue}
And some text

after the dialogue.

\end{document}
```

[image: result]